# What are the benefits of naming a callback function, which could be anonymous?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I've noticed the documentation for `Sails.js` explicitly names, what seemingly could be anonymous, callback functions - see examples below.

```
User.create({ name: 'Jamie' }).exec(function(err, created){
    ...
});
```

VS

```
User.create({ name: 'Jamie' }).exec(function createCB(err, created){
    ...
});
```

What are the benefits of this approach?

Is it purely to aid in debugging call stack outputs and readability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two reasons I can think of:

1. For debugging (as you mention).  **This gives you a named function on the call stack** in the debugger instead of just an unnamed anonymous reference.  This is most useful if someone just hands you a copy of a call stack and you aren't running it live in the debugger.  If you are running it live in the debugger, you can always just click on an element of the call stack or look at the referenced line number to see what function it actually is.
2. **It allows the function to potentially call itself** from its own implementation if that is useful or needed.  But, this name is only available within the function itself so it can't be used elsewhere and does not pollute whatever the local namespace is with another name (thus retaining that benefit of an anonymous function).